# How to follow alias with libldap?

Tags: objective-c, ldap

I have an openvpn plugin which allows me to use ldap authentication. But my LDAP directory contains aliases and it seems that openvpn-auth-ldap doesn't follow them.

```
- (id) initWithURL: (LFString *) url timeout: (int) timeout {
...
  ldap_initialize(&ldapConn, [url cString]);
        if (!ldapConn) {
                [TRLog error: "Unable to initialize LDAP server %s", [url cString]];
                [self release];
                return (NULL);
        }
        _timeout = timeout;
        ldapTimeout.tv_sec = _timeout;
        ldapTimeout.tv_usec = 0;

        if (ldap_set_option(ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, &ldapTimeout) != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS)
                [TRLog warning: "Unable to set LDAP network timeout."];
```

Is there anyway I can fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, LDAP_OPT_DEREF is setted to LDAP_DEREF_NEVER. Maybe you should force alias deferencing of your ldap connection :

```
int deref = LDAP_DEREF_ALWAYS;
ldap_set_option(ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_DEREF, &deref)
```